# How to use multiple ColumnDataSource and update all of them at once?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, synchronization, bokeh

I am developing Bokeh Server Application. I am using Bokeh `0.12.15`.

### Problem description

I have a bunch of figures plotted as you can see in the following image. When I select some points points some profile lines should be drawn in all the plots. But the problem is that they crash as you can see in this image.

[image]

If I zoom out on the two figures they become normal again. I thinks it is a synchronization issue.

I have a ColumnDataSource (CDS) available for all the plots. Each profile has its own CDS.

This is the code snippet where I update the source data for the profile lines and where I recreate the CDSview with the selected indexes for the profile circles. This code is executed once per plot. If there are 4 plots in the form and there are 3 profiles per plot, there will be 24 updates (one per CDS) if the user make some selection. Is there a way to update everything at once to avoid this issue?

```
prof_len = len(prof_cds)
prof_to_show = []
for i in range(prof_len):
    pos = NPROF - i - 1
    self.prof_lines[pos].data_source.data = prof_cds[i].data
    view = CDSView(source=self.env.source, filters=[IndexFilter(prof_indexes[i])])
    self.prof_circles[pos].view = view
    prof_to_show.append(pos)
```

In fact if I do this and I make a pause with sleep the profile lines are working well

```
prof_len = len(prof_cds)
prof_to_show = []
import time
for i in range(prof_len):
    pos = NPROF - i - 1
    self.prof_lines[pos].data_source.data = prof_cds[i].data

    lg.info('-- WAITING FOR UPDATE')
    time.sleep(2)

    view = CDSView(source=self.env.source, filters=[IndexFilter(prof_indexes[i])])
    self.prof_circles[pos].view = view
    prof_to_show.append(pos)
```

[image]

### Failed workaround

Bryan (Bokeh developer) told me to use the `hold` method, but the same problem appears

> I've only had a chance to barely glance at this, but offhand to answer your last question, perhaps `hold` and `unhold` would be useful to batch thing more: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/howto/hold_app.py

```
self.env.doc.hold('combine')
for p_obj in self.env.bk_plots:
    p_obj.plot_profile_lines(new.indices)
self.env.doc.unhold()
```

### Conclusion

I reckon the problem here is that I am using a CDS for the points and a different CDS for the profiles lines. I would like to use the same and apply some CDSView, But it is not possible due to [**this filtering behaviour**](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7594). So the only way to achieve this is to use only one CDS as it is describe in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37185548/4891717)? Then, I would need to add many columns to the current source and most of the data of these columns would have `NaN` values, it is kind of ugly.

Is there a better way to do this?

### Update 04/12/2018

- I get errors with `time.sleep` as well.
- I am going to try to plot the profiles in a different way, maybe using one CDS for them and several CDSViews, maybe using segments rather than lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. I solve it by using the `Multiline` glyph. Like this I only need to use a `ColumDataSource` to make all the line updates. It is more efficient and the app do not crash.

**Note**: But I found another [**setback**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49895574/why-is-the-plotting-order-not-respected-when-i-plot-a-circle-and-a-multiline-lat/49897154)

Answer (score 0):

How about delay the code by `add_timeout_callback`:

```
prof_len = len(prof_cds)
prof_to_show = []
import time
for i in range(prof_len):
    pos = NPROF - i - 1
    self.prof_lines[pos].data_source.data = prof_cds[i].data
    def callback(i=i, pos=pos):
        view = CDSView(source=self.env.source, filters=[IndexFilter(prof_indexes[i])])
        self.prof_circles[pos].view = view
        prof_to_show.append(pos)
    curdoc().add_timeout_callback(callback, 100)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am getting the same problems. I will try to do it in a different way. I have just checked that with `time.sleep` I am also getting errors sometimes.